# how to display a text typed in the first textbox as a slug in the second textbox?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hi all I'm trying to generate a slug in the second textbox but it cant be displayed, I only get an error:

Use of undefined constant slug - assumed 'slug' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Kwakhanya-Centre\resources\views\admin\subjects\create.blade.php)

here is my code: create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('main-content')
    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <h1 class="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800">{{ __('Create New Subject') }}</h1>
    <hr/>
    @if (session('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success border-left-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        {{ session('message') }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    @endif
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('subjects.store')}}">                
        @csrf
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="font-weight-bold">Subject Details:</h4>
                    <hr>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name" class="font-weight-bold">Subject Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" v-model="name" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" id="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
                                    @error('name')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name" class="font-weight-bold">Slug</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="slug" class="form-control @error('slug') is-invalid @enderror" id="slug" value="{{ slug }}">
                                    @error('slug')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="description" class="font-weight-bold">Description</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control  @error('description') is-invalid @enderror" id="description" value="{{ old('description') }}">
                                    @error('description')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                             
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Permissions -->
                
                <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fas fa-book fa-fw mr-2"></i>Create Subject</button> 
                    <a href="/grades"  class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg ml-4"><i class="fas fa-ban fa-fw mr-2"></i>Cancel</a>                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
@endsection

@section('js_index_page')
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            name: "",
        },
  computed: {
    slug: function() {
      var slug = this.sanitizeTitle(this.name);
      return slug;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sanitizeTitle: function(name) {
      var slug = "";
      // Change to lower case
      var nameLower = name.toLowerCase();
      // Letter "e"
      slug = nameLower.replace(/e|é|è|ẽ|ẻ|ẹ|ê|ế|ề|ễ|ể|ệ/gi, 'e');
      // Letter "a"
      slug = slug.replace(/a|á|à|ã|ả|ạ|ă|ắ|ằ|ẵ|ẳ|ặ|â|ấ|ầ|ẫ|ẩ|ậ/gi, 'a');
      // Letter "o"
      slug = slug.replace(/o|ó|ò|õ|ỏ|ọ|ô|ố|ồ|ỗ|ổ|ộ|ơ|ớ|ờ|ỡ|ở|ợ/gi, 'o');
      // Letter "u"
      slug = slug.replace(/u|ú|ù|ũ|ủ|ụ|ư|ứ|ừ|ữ|ử|ự/gi, 'u');
      // Letter "d"
      slug = slug.replace(/đ/gi, 'd');
      // Trim the last whitespace
      slug = slug.replace(/\s*$/g, '');
      // Change whitespace to "-"
      slug = slug.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
      
      return slug;
    }
  }
});
</script>

@endsection
```

everything else is working fine, but how do I display the text I typed in the first text box to the second textbox as a slug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `value="{{ slug }}"` when you should be binding the value instead

```
:value="slug"
```